# How to set Kendo Datepicker to have value convertible to Datetime

Tags: c#, kendo-datepicker

I have a Kendo Datepicker as follow

```
Html.Kendo().DatePicker()
        .Name("BirthDate")
        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "font-size:8pt;" })
        .Format("yyyy/MM/dd")
```

However, its returned value in model as follow can not be converted to Datetime using Datetime.Parse

```
"Mon Oct 15 1984 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)"
```

I want to know how to make DatePicker return value in Date only. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use kendo.toString to format

Try this:

```
<script>
    var datepicker = $("#BirthDate").data("kendoDatePicker");
    var value = datepicker.value();
    kendo.toString(value,"MM-dd-yyyy h:mm:ss tt ");
</script>
```

Comment: @user585440 Did the answer workout for you? If yes please mark the answer as correct. it will help others having similar doubts. Thanks!